# Anonymous type vs tuple in Linq query, performance considerations

Tags: c#, linq, tuples, anonymous-types

This question is specifically in the context of in-memory data, and not related to query translation frameworks (eg. not related to Entity Framework and how it can and can't transcribe certain Linq queries).

Assuming we have an `IEnumerable` containing type:

```
class Exemplar 
{
    public Guid UniqueId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string[] FriendNames { get; set; }
}


var exampleData = new List<Exemplar>(); // pretend I'm populated
```

and our business rules are something like:

- An `Exemplar` is invalid if its `FriendNames` contains an entry that does not appear as a `Name` of another `Exemplar` in our `exampleData`
- If an invalid `Exemplar` is found, write out it's `UniqueId` and its invalid `FriendNames`

I'm used to writing Linq queries that use anonymous types as intermediate structures in the chain. For example:

```
var invalidExemplars =
    exampleData
        .Select(x =>
            new
            {
                Id = x.UniqueId,
                InvalidNames = x.FriendNames.Where(n => exampleData.All(d => d.Name != n)).ToArray()
            })
        .Where(x => x.InvalidNames.Any());

// added for completion, maybe irrelevant to the question
if (invalidExemplars.Any())
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, invalidExemplars.Select(x => $"{x.Id}: [{ string.Join(",", x.InvalidNames)}]")));
}
```

But now with C# 7 we can instead use the new tuple shorthand instead of the anonymous type:

```
var invalidExemplars =
    exampleData
        .Select(x =>
        (
            Id: x.UniqueId,
            InvalidNames: x.FriendNames.Where(n => exampleData.All(d => d.Name != n)).ToArray()
        ))
        .Where(x => x.InvalidNames.Any());
```

My question is are there any performance differences between an intermediary anonymous type vs an intermediary tuple, and if so what are they?

Is there any reason (other than personal preference) to choose one over the other *as an intermediary*?

Comment: An anonymous type is an allocation, however is generally acceptable to orms, value tuple is a value type, generally stack allocated and not supported by orms. However, no need to ask us which is more performant , race your horses

Comment: @TheGeneral Yeah as mentioned at the top, the question is not related to how either of these interacts with query-transcribing frameworks. You are correct that I could "race my horses", and depending on the day, external performance load, and how thoroughly I cover the various ways I might use one or the other, I'll likely get different results. I'm hoping for an informed answer as to how .Net handles them in this intermediate context, and how each would affect performance.

Comment: The reasons why you want an informed answer, is the exact reasons you need to race your horses.  https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: @TheGeneral hopefully I didn't imply in my question that I'm interested in "faster". I'm interested in performance, for example *"using X will put data on the stack , whereas Y will use the heap, given the intermediary usage, it's better to use X/Y because stack/heap GC is more efficient"* may be *part* of a valid answer here. I can remove all references to "performance" from the question if that will assuage your concerns?

Comment: There are some very subtle differences with anonymous types and value tuples, this would be in regards to equality, storage, parameter naming, how you can pass them to other methods. since this is intermediary, the value type will likely be heap allocated anyway because of LINQ, and expression trees and orms are out of the equation, there is very little difference at all, however there will likely be subtle and fairly unnoticeable performance differences. So the answer really comes down to pick your favourite.

Comment: @TheGeneral can you put that as an answer? And maybe suggest how I might improve the question? I googled this before asking it, and I couldn't find anything that answered "in a temporary/intermediary context, why would I use Anonymous Type instead of Tuple". There's the obvious "Tuple's aren't supported by X yet", and "It's difficult to consume a method that returns anonymous types, whereas tuples can be described with a simple signature", but nothing about what's happening behind the scenes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some very subtle differences with *Anonymous Types* and *Value Tuples*.

- Equality
- Storage - heaps / stack
- Parameter naming
- Expression trees
- Syntax - Construction syntax, deconstruction etc
- Usage - how you can use them as method parameters etc

Since this question is about Intermediary usage, the *Value Tuple* will likely be heap allocated anyway because of *LINQ*, *Expression Trees* and *ORMS* are out of the equation. Then there is very little difference apart from equality and syntax, additionally the performance impact will be fairly unnoticeable. So the answer really comes down to pick your favourite.

---

**Additional resources**

[Choosing between anonymous and tuple types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/choosing-between-anonymous-and-tuple)

**Tradeoffs**

> You might want to always use ValueTuple over Tuple, and anonymous
> types, but there are tradeoffs you should consider. The ValueTuple
> types are mutable, whereas Tuple are read-only. Anonymous types can be
> used in expression trees, while tuples cannot. The following table is
> an overview of some of the key differences.

**KEY DIFFERENCES**

| Name | Access modifier | Type | Custom name | Deconstruction | Expression tree |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Anonymous types | internal | class | ✔️ | ❌ | ✔️ |
| Tuple | public | class | ❌ | ❌ | ✔️ |
| ValueTuple | public | struct | ✔️ | ✔️ | ❌ |

**Performance**

> Performance between these types depends on the scenario. The major
> impact involves the tradeoff between allocations and copying. In most
> scenarios, the impact is small. When major impacts could arise,
> measurements should be taken to inform the decision.

---

**Further Reading**

- [Eric Lippert performance rant](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)
- [BenchMarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/)